# Should I ask questions I know the answer for to help build up the site?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ask even if the answer exists online](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/ask-even-if-the-answer-exists-online)

Pretty simple, Should I ask questions I know the answer for to help build up the site?

In most cases, these would be things friends and I have struggled with in the past, but not necessarily anymore.

Comment: Not an *exact* duplicate but the information contained in the answer should apply equally well to both questions, so its best to redirect information into that one thread.

Answer (score 5):

You should not do so if your sole purpose is to help build up ELL. Stack Exchange sites should grow organically, and injecting artificial questions rarely helps anyone.

However, it's perfectly OK to [ask and answer your own question right away](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/). If a particular question has given you trouble in the past, and you're pretty sure that there are other people who have the same question, then it's fine to ask and answer that question.

Comment: +1. If you're asking a question, there is also a checkbox near "Post the Question" button allowing you to post both Q+A together. This will help others not to waste their time answering while you're writing your answer.

Comment: I know that SE policy allows for (maybe even invites) people to provide answers to their own questions, and I understand that there may be situations when such a thing makes sense. However, I find it extremely disturbing to have someone write a question and answer it immediately, it strikes me as if they were not even giving me the chance to supply my own reply, as if it were an attempt at showing off.